# Customize default_pagination number styling in Shopify

Tags: html, css, pagination, shopify, liquid

I am trying to customize the numbers for the default_pagination filter. I need to show a box around the numbers. So for this, I need to create a custom class for the numbers, and change the style in CSS. But I can't figure out how to do it. A bit of help will be much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    {% paginate collection.products by 5 %}
        {% for product in collection.products %}
            <a href="{{ product.url }}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
                <figcaption>{{ product.title }} 
                    {% if product.compare_at_price_max > 0 %}
                        <span>{{ product.compare_at_price_max | money }}</span>
                        <span>{{ product.price | money }}</span>
                    {% else %} 
                        <span>{{ product.price | money }}</span>
                    {% endif %}
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    {{ paginate | default_pagination: next: '>', previous: '<' }}   
   {% endpaginate %}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please add a screenshot of the pagination inspection window?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Shopify Liquid's `default_pagination` [filter](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/additional-filters#default_pagination) which creates a boilerplate pagination component for you, you can create a fully customizable pagination like this:

```
<nav class="Pagination">
  <ul class="Pagination__List">
    {%- if paginate.previous -%}
      <li>
        <a
          class="Pagination__Item Pagination__Item--Next" 
          href="{{ paginate.previous.url }}"
          >
          Next Page
        </a>
      </li>
    {%- endif -%}

    {%- for part in paginate.parts -%}
      <li>
        {%- if part.is_link -%}
          <a
            class="Pagination__Item"
            href="{{ part.url }}"
            >
            {{ part.title }}
          </a>
        {%- else -%}
          {%- if part.title == paginate.current_page -%}
            <span class="Pagination__Item Pagination__Item--Current">{{ part.title }}</span>
          {%- else -%}
            <span class="Pagination__Item">{{ part.title }}</span>
          {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}

    {%- if paginate.next -%}
      <li>
        <a
          class="Pagination__Item Pagination__Item--Prev"
          href="{{ paginate.next.url }}"
          >
          Previous Page
        </a>
      </li>
    {%- endif -%}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Check out the Liquid [paginate object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/paginate) for more information.

Styling it the way you want should be quite easy then. Comment if you need help with that. I'm happy to help :)